# C#: How to get single file diff using pre-commit hook

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have committed 2 files in SVN. I can able to get diff of committed files using pre-commit hook. Please find the below comments for getting diff

```
string commandLineArguments = string.Format("diff --transaction {0} \"{1}\"", transactionName, repositoryPath);
string output = GetSvnlookOutput(commandLineArguments);
```

I need only one file diference. please find below example.
EX:
  Committed **sample1.cs** and **sample2.cs**. but i need **sample1.cs** svn dfference only.
 Is any possible to get single file differnce based on filename?.